# QNetworkAccessManager timeout

Tags: qt, networking

Presently I am working on an application which sends and receives file from remote server. To do network operation I am using QNetworkAccessManager.

To upload a file I am using QNetworkAccessManager::put() and to download I am using QNetworkAccessManager::get() functions.

While uploading a file I will initialize a timer with time out of 15 sec. if I upload a small file it will complete it within the time out period. But if I try to upload a file which is very large in size get time out. So how to decide time out for uploading of large file.

Same in case of downloading of a large file. I get file in chunk by chunk in readyread() signal. Here also if I download a large file I get time out. So how to decide time out for uploading of large file.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use the [`QNetworkReply::uploadProgress()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkreply.html#uploadProgress) (or [`downloadProgress`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkreply.html#downloadProgress)) signal to alert you that the operation is progressing. Then, set a timer for 15 seconds after the last `uploadProgress`/`downloadProgress` notification (with the timer started when the download/upload commenced.) If the download ever stops, you can cancel the operation 15 seconds after the last update.

Comment: How to cancel download operation and make  QNetworkReply to emit httpFinished() ?

Comment: @Temak use `reply->abort()` and `emit reply->finished()`

Comment: @Kolyunya There is feature request on qt bug tracker that's been hanging around for about 5 years or something like that. Feel free to upvote it.

Comment: (Just a note:) Above-mentioned feature request is [here](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-3443)