# Detecting ip camera connection using QNetworkAccessManager?

Tags: c++, qt, ip-camera, qnetworkaccessmanager, qnetworkreply

I'm using two ip cameras from Axis Communications for my application. I want to check if the cameras are ever disconnected. Is it possible to do so by the use of `QNetworkAccessManager` and `QNetworkReply`?

The prototype of what I tried is like the following way:

```
QNetworkAccessManager *m_networkAccessManager = new QNetworkAccessManager();
QNetworkReply *m_networkReply = m_networkAccessManager->get(QNetworkRequest(camUrl));
if (!m_networkReply)
{
   delete m_networkAccessManager;
   qDebug()<<"Camera not found"<<endl;
}

connect(m_networkReplyCam, SIGNAL(error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)), this, SLOT(cameraDisconnected(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)));

void MainWindow::cameraDisconnected(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)
{
    qDebug()<<"Camera Disconected"<<endl;
}
```

But the slot `cameraDisconnected` never seem to gets invoked. I also tried connect with `finished()` signal from `QNetworkReply` like the following:

```
connect(m_networkReplyCam, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(cameraDisconnected()));
```

But even then the slot never gets called.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your request will *timeout* after some time if the host is unreachable. There is no built-in way to set specific timeout in `QNetworkRequest`or `QNetworkAccessManager` so one possibility is to implement your own timer to abort after a particular time. There are multiple examples to do that like [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668519/qnetworkaccessmanager-timeout), [2](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/30031/qnetworkreply-network-reply-timeout-helper) and [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13207493/qnetworkreply-and-qnetworkaccessmanager-timeout-in-http-request).